# Normalizer of a subgroup in $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\otimes 2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Does anyone know a fast method/algorithm for calculating the normalizer of an abelian subgroup $G$ of $  \mathbb{Z}_2^{\otimes 2n}$ (equipped with a symplectic inner product)? Or do I need to check element by element if it belongs to the Normalizer of $G$?

**Edit:** I should have said, the commutator of two elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\otimes 2n}$ is given by $[g_1, g_2] = g_1 \tilde{\cdot} g_2 = g_1[:n]\cdot g_2[n:] - g_1[n:]\cdot g_2[:n]$. Thus, the Normalizer will be all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\otimes 2n}$ such that the inner product with $G$ is $0$ (mod 2). Is there an easy way to get a generating set of $N(G)$?

Comment: Tensor product of abelian groups is itself abelian, so wouldn't the normaliser coincide with the whole group?

Comment: The comment by @lisyarus is correct. I think you might have meant (not a normalizer in $(\mathbb Z_2)^{\otimes 2n}$ but rather) a stabilizer in the symplectic group acting on $(\mathbb Z_2)^{\otimes 2n}$.

Comment: My mistake, I should have said that the commutator of two elements is given by the symplectic product between them, i.e. $[1000, 0010 ] = (10) \cdot (10) - (00) \cdot (00) = 1$ (here the symplectic product is the dot product between the first two halves minus the second two halves of the bit strings).

Comment: You mean a direct sum, not a tensor product. And this is not a normalizer; it's called the symplectic complement. It's defined by a set of linear equations over $\mathbb{F}_2$ so you just use row reduction.